# Possible to use getElementsByClassName with an external HTML file?

Tags: javascript

I have a test.html file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">
      FOO
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">
      BAR
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which I can simply parse like this:

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("outside");
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByClassName("inside")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
</script>
```

To get the result I want:

```
FOO
BAR
```

But I would like to parse the content of test.html in another HTML file. I've tried using XMLHttpRequest like this:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","test.html",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("outside");
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) 
document.write(x[i].getElementsByClassName("inside")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName')
```

Using all files on my local web server so shouldn't be any issues with access. I know that this certainly isn't the most modern way of parsing but its something I'm just gonna be using locally for a hobby project. But if you have any suggestions on how to solve this with jQuery for example, I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: Well that is not valid XML....

Comment: From what I've read HTML should to be supported with XMLHttpRequest. But I could certainly be wrong.

Comment: Yes, but HTML is not XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to use responseXML when the document is not HTML.

You would need to set the html of a div with the responseText and query that.

```js
var str = "<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li>";  //xmlhttp.responseText;
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = str;
var lis = div.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i=0;i<lis.length; i++) {
    console.log(lis[i].textContent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Took a little while (cuz I'm sorta code slow) to figure out that I can use xmlhttp.request to get the entire page. This is my final working code `var str = xmlhttp.response;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = str;
    var x=div.getElementsByClassName("outside");
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) 
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByClassName("inside")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);`